# Grading system in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

So this is my C++ question :

Write a program that translates a letter grade into a number grade. Letter grades are A, B, C, D and F, possibly followed by + or -. Their numeric values are 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0. There is no F+ or F-. A + increases the numeric value by 0.3, a – decreases it by 0.3. However, an A+ has value 4.0.

Enter a letter grade: B
The numeric value is 2.7

And here is my code :

```
int main ()
{
    char grade;
    int value;
    cout << "Enter letter grade : " ;
    cin >> grade;

    switch(grade)
    {
    case 'A' : value = 4;
        break;
    case 'B' : value =  3;
        break;
    case 'C' : value = 2;
        break;
    case 'D' : value = 1;
        break;
    case 'E' : value = 0;
        break;
    default : cout << "Wrong input " << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << value;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It able to print out 4 for A, 3 for B and so on. But however, the question required us to make the calculation for the + and - also. Am I supposed to use if else statement after the switch?

Comment: First, your char variable grade cannot take strings which consist of more than single character i.e., A+, A-. So use char array instead.

Second, then using if on string comparisons will be easier.

Please redesign.

Comment: The question also seems to suggest that 'B' should be worth 3, and then it's given as an example worth 2.7...

Comment: That's why type of value should not be 'int'

Comment: I had some time to spare (on a break), so I figured I'd whip something up for fun. [Here's a link to the working code](http://ideone.com/ax6mhj) You can see the different outputs, depending on the input, at the bottom of the page. Hopefully, you'll find it useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is `A+` or `B-`, then it is not a character anymore. So, get it using a string of chars, and check the values.

```
char a[3];
float m,n;
cin>>a;
if(a[1]=='+')
   m=0.3;
else if (a[1]=='-')
   m=-0.3;
else
    m=0;
switch(a[0])
{
  //Assign the value of n as 4,3,2,1 depending upon the grade.
}
cout<<n+m;
```

will print the grade

Comment: How about this? the grade is not changed if there is no `+` or `-`. If there is none, then a[1] will be `\0`

Comment: Where is the storage for termination symbol null?

Comment: if the second character is null, it will be `\0` and m will be assigned `0`. So what is the problem here?

Comment: It works but I want to know what's the char a[3]? I thought it supposed to be char a[1] since A+,A- only contains two char.

Comment: That's the storage for null termination. You need to allocate an extra byte for that.

Comment: @Rauryn: char a[1] takes only 1 character. a[2] takes two characters, but we need a place to store the string terminator `\0`. So we allocated three bytes of memory. char a[3]

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding more cases would help. Modifying your code as below:

```
    int main ()
    {
    String grade;
    float value;
    cout << "Enter letter grade : " ;
    cin >> grade;

    switch(grade)
    {
    case "A" : value = 4;
        break;
    case "A+" : value = 4.3;
        break;
    case "A-" : value = 3.7;
        break;
    case "B" : value = 3;
        break;
    case "B+" : value = 3.3;
        break;
    case "B-" : value = 2.7;
        break;        
    case "C" : value = 2;
        break;
    case "C+" : value = 2.3;
        break;
    case "C-" : value = 1.7;
        break;        
    case "D" : value = 1;
        break;
    case "D+" : value = 1.3;
        break;
    case "D-" : value = 0.7;
        break;        
    case "F" : value = 0;
        break;
    default : cout << "Wrong input " << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << value;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

    }
```

This is a straightforward extension of what you did, there can be million other ways.

Comment: Okay okay I've thought of this too but it's too long. Thanks tho

Comment: The statement containing case 'F' should be in double quotes. Please correct.

Comment: It works fine, but it's clunky and not at all extensible. And, I suspect, you get more marks for writing something that expresses in code the idea of + and - being modifiers, rather than "B+" having an absolute value in a lookup table.

Comment: Is it possible to use a string in a switch statement?

Comment: No. C++ string cannot be used in switch statement as it is not defined as type but class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd deal with each character in turn. You know that the first one should be a letter grade, so you look at that one first, and you could just use a switch statement like you've already got for that.

```
uint value = 0;
char grade_letter = grade[0];

switch (grade_letter) {
    // assign value as appropriate
}
```

Then, if the second character exists, check if it's a + or a - and modify the value you got from the switch statement accordingly.

```
if (grade.length() > 1) {
    char modifier = grade[1];
    switch (modifier) {
        case '+': value += 0.3;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Before all that of course, you'll want to check for the special case of A+ and skip everything else.

An alternative approach would be to replace the switch statements with lookups in a previously-prepared data structure, something like a `std::map<char, int>`, which, even if the initialisation code prepared it from hardcoded data, would open the way to loading the grade information from a configuration file or database at some point in the future. Special-casing A+ in that case becomes slightly trickier though.

Comment: As OP mentioned other characters than F can also be followed by + or -. So special case is not A but F?

Comment: But there's an error at the char grade_letter = grade[0]; this line

Comment: @Rauryn it's not a complete solution, just intended to be an idea of what might be a good way to do it, and assumes some things from your original code.