# C++ Grading System

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

So I trying to do a grade system in C++. For example, an A+ will gives 4.0, A gives 4.0 and A- gives 3.7. For each + - there's 0.3 difference. Here is my code :

```
        char grade_letter[3];
float value; 
bool input = true;

do{
    cout << "Enter letter grade : ";
    cin>>grade_letter;

    switch(grade_letter[0])
    {
    case 'A' : value = 4;
        break;
    case 'B' : value = 3;
        break;
    case 'C' : value = 2;
        break;
    case 'D' : value = 1;
        break;
    case 'E' : value = 0;
        break;
    }

    if(grade_letter[1]=='+'){
        value += 0.3;
    }
    else if (grade_letter[1]=='-'){
        value -= 0.3;
    }

    if (input == true){
        if(value > 4.0){
            cout << "The numeric value is " << floor(value + 0.5) << endl;
        }else if (value < 0.0){
            cout << "Grade out of range. " << endl;
        }else{
            cout<< "The numeric value is " << value <<  endl;
        }
    }else {
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
    }
}while(input == false);
```

It works when I tried with A+ A and A-. But however, I tried with A=, A/, A*, the result still shows the default value for each grade. There's something wrong with the validation.

If I set the boolean input default value to false, it only works with A+ A- and so on, as long as there's + and - in the input. I thinking of using string and substring to read the input but if so, I've to recode everything.

So, can somebody please help with my validation? I trying to check the length of char grade_letter using charAt but there's an error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asked this some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188085/grading-system-in-c

Comment: @DanielDaranas I guess that was the previous step.

Comment: @sftrabbit Probably, but the titles say nothing about the real question in both cases and this causes confusion.

Comment: Ya ya that one without validation. I'd my lesson today and my teacher asks for validation. I tried already but it just can't works

Answer (score 2):

After you check for `'+'` and `'-'` you need to add a check that no other character is there:

```
if(grade_letter[1]=='+'){
    value += 0.3;
}
else if (grade_letter[1]=='-'){
    value -= 0.3;
} else if (grade_letter[1]!='\0'){
    /* Error */
}
```

Comment: It works. Simple and clear. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `input` to `false`. Perhaps you want another `else` after checking that the second character is a `-` that will do `input = false`?

```
if(grade_letter[1]=='+'){
    value += 0.3;
}
else if (grade_letter[1]=='-'){
    value -= 0.3;
}
else {
    input = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes: (1) add a default to your switch to set input to false, (2) add an else to the series of if statements which check for a + or - so that if there is some character other than an end of string, input will be set to false, and (3) move the check on the + or - sign to after the check that input is true.

```
char grade_letter[3];
float value; 
bool input = true;

do{
    cout << "Enter letter grade : ";
    cin>>grade_letter;

    switch(grade_letter[0])
    {
    case 'A' : value = 4;
        break;
    case 'B' : value = 3;
        break;
    case 'C' : value = 2;
        break;
    case 'D' : value = 1;
        break;
    case 'E' : value = 0;
        break;
    default:
        input = false;
        break;
    }

    if (input == true){
        if(grade_letter[1]=='+'){
            value += 0.3;
        }
        else if (grade_letter[1]=='-'){
            value -= 0.3;
        } else if (grade_letter[1]){
            // something other than end of string so bad input
            input = false;
        }
        if (input) {
            if(value > 4.0){
                cout << "The numeric value is " << floor(value + 0.5) << endl;
            }else if (value < 0.0){
                cout << "Grade out of range. " << endl;
            }else{
                cout<< "The numeric value is " << value <<  endl;
            }
        }
    }
    if (! input) {
        // at some point we have bad input so let user know.
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
    }
}while(input == false);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you miss two places in your validation.

First, grade letter:

```
switch(grade_letter[0])
{
case 'A' : value = 4;
    break;
case 'B' : value = 3;
    break;
case 'C' : value = 2;
    break;
case 'D' : value = 1;
    break;
case 'E' : value = 0;
    break;
default: 
    valid = false;  // What we don't recognize is invalid
    break;
}
```

And then the second part validation:

```
if (valid)  // continue verification only if valid
{
    switch(grade_letter[1])
    {
    case '+': value += 0.3; break;
    case '-': value -= 0.3; break;
    case ' ': 
    case '\0': break; // we assume space and EOL is OK
    default: valid = false; break;
    }
}
```